# Adding a hidden UIITextField to MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to dismiss the keyboard on MFMailComposeViewController after a certain amount of time on my app, To do this i have added a timer and a hidden text field on MFMailComposeViewController, Once the timer triggers i dismiss the keyboard, Will this be a problem for rejecting apps by apple on app store ?

Code

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class mailViewController : UIViewController , MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tempTextField : UITextField?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        //var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(4, target: self, selector: "dismissKeyBoard", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)



         let mailComposeViewController = configuredMailComposeViewController()
         if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {

            tempTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 400))
            tempTextField!.delegate = self
            tempTextField!.hidden = true
            mailComposeViewController.view.addSubview(tempTextField!)

            var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10, target: self, selector: "goToHome", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

            self.presentViewController(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

         } else {
            self.showSendMailErrorAlert()
         }

        let bounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        let width = bounds.size.width
        let height = bounds.size.height

        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height);
        let testLayer = CustomView(frame: rect)
        testLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        //mailComposeViewController.view.addSubview(testLayer)

        //UIWindow* keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
        //UIView* firstResponder = [keyWindow performSelector:@selector(firstResponder)];
        //[firstResponder resignFirstResponder];

        var keyWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
        //var firstResponder = keyWindow?.performSelector(firstResponder)
        //firstResponder.re

    }

    @IBAction func sendEmailButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        let mailComposeViewController = configuredMailComposeViewController()
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            self.presentViewController(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            self.showSendMailErrorAlert()
        }
    }

    func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
        let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self // Extremely important to set the --mailComposeDelegate-- property, NOT the --delegate-- property

        mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["someone@somewhere.com"])
        mailComposerVC.setSubject("Sending you an in-app e-mail...")
        mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("Sending e-mail in-app is not so bad!", isHTML: false)

        return mailComposerVC
    }

    func showSendMailErrorAlert() {
        let sendMailErrorAlert = UIAlertView(title: "Could Not Send Email", message: "Your device could not send e-mail.  Please check e-mail configuration and try again.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        sendMailErrorAlert.show()
    }

    // MARK: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate Method
    func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController!, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError!) {
        controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        print("inside mail composer view")
    }

    func dismissKeyBoard(){
        print("dismiss the keyboard now ....")
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        print("view did disappear got called !!!!")
    }

    func goToHome(){

        print("timer ended")
        //var goToHome = ViewController()
        //self.presentViewController(goToHome, animated: true, completion: nil)
        tempTextField?.becomeFirstResponder()
        tempTextField?.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be having problem with the below line. Because it might be violating Apple Guidelines.

```
mailComposeViewController.view.addSubview(tempTextField!)
```

You cannot add any controller or you cannot add any subviews to
MFMailComposeViewController.

As per apple guidelines application should not interrupt user process/tasks till user allows or finished the process.

Comment: What if a user is logged in....and stays ideal on mailComposeViewController for a  long time and he automatically times out ? and gets redirected to login screen ?

Comment: In that case you might have to find alternate way for mail functionality. you can try with WebServices by customising your UI like MFMailComposeViewController. Because as per apple guidelines it might not allowed this way..!!!

Answer (score -1):

> Nope , your codes looking clear and i think that way dont problem for Apple,

Also you can see more information about common rejections issues here;
https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/rejections/

Good Luck !